# Discord - Screenshot Embed Messages

Tags: python, node.js, discord, discord.js, discord.py

What I'm trying to acheive here is:

I want to create a Discord Bot that will find Embeded messages sent in a particular channel, and Screenshot them.

[image]

I'm not really sure of any good way to do this. The only way I've been doing it now is by manually screenshotting them 1 by 1.

Anyone know of any way to do this automatically? Perheaps using Selenium/Puppeteer or a Discord Bot in Python?

Comment: Does it have to be a picture or can it just be the content of embed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bot access you have to look through the channel history and find messages with embeds, and extract the contents of the embed. If you actually need pictures, then you will have to replicate the HTML markup of a Discord message. For this, you can reverse-engineer an embed generator webapp such as [this one](https://cog-creators.github.io/discord-embed-sandbox/) and implement its features in your Python code.

After that, you can put this HTML, along with the appropriate CSS, into Selenium, and [take a screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6282203/5936187) of the new page containing only the embed.